# How to remove redundant vm on vmware fusion right click?

Tags: macos, mac, mac-mini, vmware

[image]

if I right click ,I saw two vm, the top one needs to be removed as it give me
no response after click.
the second one needs to stay.
Tried this in terminal and no changes.

```
System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Support/lsregister -kill -r -domain local -domain system -domain user
```

Comment: On my Intel Mac, I would open VMware Fusion and delete the virtual machine from the Virtual Machine Library.